# Showing that a $\sigma$-algebra is independent of itself iff $\mathbb P(A)\in\{0,1\}$ for each set in the $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Show that a $\sigma$-algebra is independent of itself iff $\mathbb
>  P(A)\in\{0,1\}$ for each set in the $\sigma$-algebra.

**My try:**

For the first direction, suppose that the $\sigma$-algebra is independent of itself. Then

$$\mathbb P(A_j\cap A_k)=\mathbb P(A_j)\cdot \mathbb P(A_k)$$

for each $j\neq k$. (Is this what is meant by independent of itself?) Since a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complementation, then it must be the case that

$$\mathbb P(A_j\cap A_j^c)=\mathbb P(A_j)\cdot \mathbb P(A_j^c)$$

for each $j$. But since $A_j\cap A_j^c=\emptyset$ and $\mathbb P(\emptyset)=0$ then it must be the case that $\mathbb P(A_j)\in\{0,1\}\Leftrightarrow \mathbb P(A_j^c)\in\{0,1\}$.

For the other direction, suppose $\mathbb P(A_j)\in\{0,1\}$ for each $j$. Then

$$\mathbb P(A_j)\cdot \mathbb P(A_k)\in\{0,1\}$$

for all $j\neq k$. However, it's not clear to me why this would imply

$$\mathbb P(A_j\cap A_k)=\mathbb P(A_j)\cdot \mathbb P(A_k)$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. If there were an event $A$ with $0<\mathbb P(A)<1$, then $$\mathbb P(A\cap A) = \mathbb P(A) > \mathbb P(A)^2 = \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(A).$$

Comment: Ah okay I see. And I suppose you can use a contradiction to show the converse. Suppose $\mathbb P(A)\in\{0,1\}$ and that the $\sigma$-algebra is not independent of itself. Then $$\mathbb P(A\cap A)\neq \mathbb P(A)\cdot\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(A)^2=\mathbb P(A)$$ which is a contradiction since $\mathbb P(A\cap A)=\mathbb P(A)$

Comment: However, the phrase "independent of itself" is not clear to me in the case of a $\sigma$-algebra. Don't we need to show that the converse is true for all pairwise sets?

Comment: @Remy Not sure this works, because not being self-independent doesn't mean there aren't any independent pairs of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an axiomatic proof, but I hope it helps for the *only if* part.

Using the property that $A \subset B \implies P(A) \leq P(B)$, we get the conditions
$$\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  A_j \cap A_k \subset A_j \implies P(A_j\cap A_k) \leq P(A_j)\\
                  A_j \cap A_k \subset A_k \implies P(A_j\cap A_k) \leq P(A_k)
                \end{array}
              \right.$$
Then if either $P(A_j) = 0$ or $P(A_k)=0$, $P(A_j\cap A_k) \in \{0,1\} \implies P(A_j\cap A_k)=0$. On the other hand, if both $P(A_j) = 1$ and $P(A_k) = 1$, then $\underbrace{P(A_j\cup A_k)}_{=1} = \underbrace{P(A_j)}_{=1}+\underbrace{P(A_k)}_{=1}-P(A_j \cap A_k) \implies P(A)=1$. So in any case, $P(A_j\cap A_k) = P(A_j)\cdot P(A_k)$.

Comment: Thanks, just fixed